# How to remote shutdown a win XP machine from linux?

Tags: linux, remote, shutdown

How do you remotely shutdown an XP host from a linux machine? I know that you can use

```
shutdown /s /f /m \IP_GOES_HERE
```

From windows, but how would you do that from linux? (wine does not port the `shutdown` command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psshutdown doesn't work from wine for some reason.

however,

```
net rpc shutdown -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U username%password
```

works if all the [proper steps](https://superuser.com/questions/107331/net-rpc-shutdown-fails-with-the-right-credentials/) have been taken

Answer (score 4):

Does the [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) tool from SysInternals (nor part of MS) work under Wine? Probably not, but might be worth a try.

Failing that you could install cygwin's OpenSSH port (or some other SSH server service) and use that to login and call Windows' own local shutdown command - this would be a one line command/script.

Comment: I'm playing with psshutdown now!

Comment: And it doesn't seem to work form wine

Answer (score 0):

I used the psshutdown, but had a different method.
I had Outlook open on the machine 24/7 and if it received an email from my email account only, with a random set of words in it, the rule would run psshutdown

you could try this
you could even use this mthod to shiut the computer off from a text message! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you create a shortcut link to this from the windows machine you can simply do it that way.

Put this in the Target text box:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -c "Shutdown!" -t 10

Put this in the Start in text box:
C:\Windows\System32