# Why does net rpc shutdown fail with the right credentials?

Tags: linux, unix, remote, shutdown

The command

```
$ net rpc SHUTDOWN -f -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U uname%psswd
```

Fails with the following errors:

```
Could not connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Could not connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

When the credentials are definitely, absolutely correct. Whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable simple file sharing on the remote host by going to

```
My Computer > Tools > Folder Options > View
```

And UNCHECK `simple file sharing`

Also punch the appropriate holes in your firewall by going

```
Control Panel > Security Center > Windows Firewall > Exceptions
```

and CHECK "File and Printer Sharing"

Also on the `Advanced tab > ICMP Settings` CHECK "Allow incoming echo request"

More info [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-remotely-shut-down-windows-xp-computers-from-a-linux-server).

Answer (score 2):

if your user name is of the form `domain\uname`, try changing the form to `domain/uname` (i.e., change the `\` to `/` )

Comment: This works for use with a domain account: DOM/username%password.  Thanks.