# Remotely shutdown Windows machine from Unix?

Tags: unix

I have a Windows 8.1 machine in LAN. I discovered `winexe` package through my research but no attempts have been successful yet. I tried:

```
winexe -U [windows-live-email-adress]%[pass] //[local-ip] `shutdown /s /t 0`
```

It says:

```
ERROR: Cannot open control pipe - NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remote shutdown a win XP machine from linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/107288/how-to-remote-shutdown-a-win-xp-machine-from-linux)

Comment: @RubanSavvy: Not quite. The other question is more generic, whereas this one is more specific.

Comment: Okay Larssend..